# Manipulating a sql table to get employees who are overbooked in a day

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have 3 Tables

```
1. Employees (empid, lname, fname, emptype, cellphone, homphone, ftpt)
2. Schedule(date, empid, dept_name, start_time, shift_length)
3. Departments(dept_name, dept manager)`
```

We have to generate a table listing all employees who are overbooked by being scheduled more than once a day.

The final table after the select statement should look like this :

[image]
it is ordered by the employee ID.

Here is the create table for the 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Departments(department_name VARCHAR(30));
CREATE TABLE Employees(empid int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, lname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, fname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, emptype VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, cellphone VARCHAR(20), homephone VARCHAR(20), ftpt VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE Schedule(date VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, empid INT NOT NULL, department VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, start_time VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, shift_length INT NOT NULL );
```

Sample data [Schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kMN8.png)
[EMPLOYEES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjCjL.png)

Files with data - 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hSf4rbGOvqrTZVyPaveF6fUAKB29Q2o_?usp=sharing

Comment: Your question lacks sufficient detail. Please post the schema for the three tables (this includes data types) as SQL statements, provide sample data, and the expected outcome.

Comment: I added the schema of the tables

Comment: Post the schema, and data as SQL statements. By posting vital information as images, you're creating barriers to users being able to help you with your question.

Comment: edited the best i could!

Comment: Now you just need to post sample data in a usable format, and clarify what condition determine whether an employee is overbooked.

Comment: The files need to be inserted hence i posted a picture of the data. You can ignore the Manager table in the output. And overbooked condition is simply scheduled more than once in a day . The output is the "final table" above

Answer (score 0):

Some of the column names you gave are inconsistent, so you may need to change some of them to match what is actually in your database. But this should get you started.

```
SELECT empid, lname as lastName, fname as firstName, date as [OVERBOOKED DATE], start_time as sfrom, Departments.dept_name as dname, dept_manager as MANAGER FROM Employees JOIN Schedule ON Employees.empid=Schedule.empid JOIN Departments on Schedule.dept_name=Departments.dept_name WHERE empid IN (SELECT empid FROM Schedule WHERE COUNT(*) > 1 GROUP BY date, empid)
```

Comment: I fixed it and am using this now : SELECT E.empid, E.lname as lastName, E.fname as firstName, S.date as OVERBOOKED_DATE, S.start_time as sfrom, D.department_name as dname, D.dept_manager as MANAGER FROM Employees E, Schedule S, Departments D JOIN Schedule ON E.empid = S.empid JOIN Departments on S.department = D.department_name WHERE E.empid IN (SELECT empid FROM Schedule WHERE COUNT(*) > 1)  GROUP BY OVERBOOKED_DATE, E.empid; BUt it gives me an error that "Invalid use of group function". I tried removing the Group By part but it still gives me that same error

Comment: The Group By needs to be inside the parenthesis after COUNT(*) > 1 and change E.empid to Schedule.empid